# Escape special characters in properties file java

Tags: java, properties

I have key, value in properties file like this `proj.path=${HOME}/dir`. I have both environment variable  and directory also with `${HOME}`.

In my case I would like to use it as directory path only but when I read this from file it is getting replaced with environment variable value `(home/user/dir)`.

I tried to escape it like `proj.path=\\$\\{HOME\\}/dir` but in code it is coming like `\$\{HOME\}/dir`

Required output is `${HOME}/dir`.

EDIT:

Prop file:

proj.path=${HOME}/dir,some/dir/dir2

I am accessing in spring like below.

`@Value("#{'${proj.path}'.split(',')}")
 private List<String> customPaths;`

Comment: How is your .properties file? < Can you explain the full context like from where you are trying to access the environment path?

Comment: you are working on Spring project??

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, I am working on spring project.

Comment: You need to read this by Spring Regular Expression Language.

Comment: In sprint Boot 2.0, the # and the split can be ommited, I think  that Sprint EL could interpret your env variable. Did you try @Value("$proj.path}")

Answer (score 0):

One way of escaping the ${HOME} value is by wrapping the $ character in an expression and changing the type from `List<String>` to `String[]`.

`proj.path=#{'$'}{HOME}/dir,some/dir/dir2`

```
@Value("${proj.path}")
private String[] customPaths;
```

Comment: Did you change the type from List<String> to String[] ? I noticed that it does not work if the type is a List.

Comment: Yes. I changed.

Comment: What version of springframework are you using? It works with 4.3.18. Please also include more details or a stacktrace of the error if possible.